# If we used the **jquery popup** in my site, and if the user block pop in the browser. Is it works?

Tags: jquery

If we used the **jquery popup** in my site, and if the user block pop in the browser. Is it works?

Comment: is there a way for `jquery popup` to be blocked?

Comment: yeah!! It not is works!.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not quite sure how "jQuery popup" works, but technically:

- if it opens a window (`window.open()`) it will get blocked by every popup blocker that is around
- if it uses `DIVs` to popup information (or any other `HTML markup`) it should work with standard popup blockers

Answer (score 1):

@DhrubaJyoti Your answer is "Yes" your jquery popup will work even if the user has popup blockers enabled.

Popup blockers look for new "windows" (popups) to be created and then block them.
However, what jquery does is not create new windows but it just creates Modal Dialog's which as standard HTML elements on the webpage with show/hide effects on it.

There is no way for a popup blocker to stop jquery dialog popups.

Examples of jQuery Dialog Popups can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/